# Adding sequential numbering to the beginning of file name using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, pdf, sequential, version-numbering

I have a series of PDF files on my computer that I am trying to rename them using Powershell by adding a sequential number starting at 1000 to the beginning of, preceded by the letter "B".

Current file naming:

```
FileNameA.pdf
FileNameB.pdf
FileNameC.pdf
```

What I want:

```
B1000 - FileNameA.pdf
B1001 - FilenameB.pdf
B1002 - FileNameC.pdf
```

I tried using the following function to achieve this:

```
$count=1000; 
dir "C:Temp" | rename-item -newname {"B {0} - {1}" -f $count++,  $_.name}
```

When I do this it renames all of the files with "B 1000" at the beginning but does not sequentially number them. Can someone help me figure out how to modify this code to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter-bound scriptblock `{"B {0} - {1}" -f $count++,$_.Name}` will run in it's own scope, meaning that any attempt to write to variables (including with `++`) will result in PowerShell hiding the variable references behind a local copy - and the value of the original `$count` variable in the parent scope will therefore remain unaffected.

Use the `script:` scope modifier to persist the modification of `$count` in the parent scope to make it work:

```
dir "C:Temp" | rename-item -newname {"B {0} - {1}" -f $script:count++, $_.name}
```

Comment: @Runwithforks That's great, you're welcome! Consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)